# Wordpress on subfolder of asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

I want my website domain subfolder to point to my website on wordpress.com, and keep the website address in the url bar the same.

For instance, the website is www.domain.com, the blog is www.domain.com/blog, and my wordpress site is mysite.wordpress.com. I want www.domain.com/blog to point to mysite.wordpress.com, but not change the url in the url bar.

The website is built on asp.net. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Uhhhhhh, generally, no.

10 years ago, when frames were acceptable you'd have a `<frameset>` page on your website and you'd load your wordpress blog into a frame and your visitors wouldn't see the wordpress.com domain name in the address bar - but frames are terrible and break things like bookmarking and site navigation, which is why they were removed from XHTML and HTML5 (their replacement, XFrames, is DoA).

Setting up a simple redirection in IIS would sort-of work, but wouldn't preserve your domain name in the address bar because your visitors *need* to connect to Wordpress directly.

The only solution, therefore, is to set up a proxy service on your website that proxies requests to your website over to Wordpress. This is no easy undertaking, but it is doable. You only need to proxy the HTML (things like images and other assets can be linked fine). You'd do this with a `IHttpHandler` in IIS that forges a new request to Wordpress and then uses a library like HtmlAgilityPack to replace appropriate URIs in the HTML with those to your proxy service.

Things like POSTable forms and Ajax requests might break - personally I don't think it's worth the hassle. I'd pay for a premium Wordpress.com subdomain, or have a local Wordpress installation.